# a sass file in react project is showing an error that i dont know where its coming from

Tags: reactjs, sass

The sass file is showing an error I don't know where its coming from.

the error log :

```
C:\Users\Mehdy\Desktop\ForumReact\src\theme\node-content-renderer.scss:184:26: 6.5 is not an int.
    ╷
184 │   @for $i from 1 through (($point-count + 1) / 2) {
    │                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  stdin 184:26  root stylesheet
Error: 6.5 is not an int.
    ╷
184 │   @for $i from 1 through (($point-count + 1) / 2) {
    │                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  stdin 184:26  root stylesheet
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-app-template@1.0.0 build: `parcel build src/index.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-app-template@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

And The part thats responsible of the error in the file (rendere.scss) :

```
@for $i from 1 through (($point-count + 1) / 2) {
    &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
      transform: rotate(360deg / $point-count * ($i - 1));
    }

    &:nth-of-type(#{$i + $point-count / 2}) {
      transform: rotate(180deg + 360deg / $point-count * ($i - 1));
    }

    &:nth-of-type(#{$i}),
    &:nth-of-type(#{$i + $point-count / 2}) {
      &:before {
        animation-delay: -$spin-animation-time +
          ($spin-animation-time / $point-count * 2 * ($i - 1));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: it seems to me the error is due to the calculated number (6.5) is not an int. It probably needs to be integer like 6 or 7.

Comment: The numbers in your `@for` loop need to be whole integers. The [`ceil()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/functions/math#ceil) or [`floor()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/functions/math#floor) functions can fix this. Example: `@for $i from 1 through ceil(($point-count + 1) / 2) {`